# .Net Excel Plugin, save setting to excel properties

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I need to develop a .NET plugin to excel. And one of the requirement is to save some settings. This setting should be displayed again after user close the excel, and display user's last input.

What is my option to do this? Do Excel have some kind of user-setting table that I can use?
I tried to avoid to create my own file or setting to achieve this.

Comment: What is the nature of the settings?  Are they cell colors, mother's maiden name and address, what? Can you use [application and user settings?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)  Most settings that are relevant to an Excel spreadsheet are saved with the spreadsheet.

Comment: basically text. can contain anything that user input. Basically to make some input automatically populated based on user last input so user does not need to re-input them. Saw the link you posted. Seems a correct way to go. Can you change your comment to answer so I can accept them once I confirmed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save something that's not part of the spreadsheet, you can use [Application and User Settings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)